# Pandas: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, attributeerror

I do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dttm_utc': pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=50, freq=pd.offsets.Minute(n=5))})
df['data1'] = np.random.randint(0, 500, len(df))
```

df is now:

```
                     data1
dttm_utc                  
2012-01-01 00:00:00    266
2012-01-01 00:05:00    384
2012-01-01 00:10:00     31
2012-01-01 00:15:00    306
2012-01-01 00:20:00    180
2012-01-01 00:25:00     58
2012-01-01 00:30:00    350
2012-01-01 00:35:00    190
2012-01-01 00:40:00    359
2012-01-01 00:45:00    493
2012-01-01 00:50:00    406
2012-01-01 00:55:00    363
2012-01-01 01:00:00    188
2012-01-01 01:05:00    446
2012-01-01 01:10:00    391
2012-01-01 01:15:00     13
2012-01-01 01:20:00    135
2012-01-01 01:25:00    220
2012-01-01 01:30:00     20
2012-01-01 01:35:00    408
2012-01-01 01:40:00    189
2012-01-01 01:45:00     70
2012-01-01 01:50:00    319
2012-01-01 01:55:00     72
2012-01-01 02:00:00    422
2012-01-01 02:05:00    307
2012-01-01 02:10:00    433
2012-01-01 02:15:00    251
2012-01-01 02:20:00    361
2012-01-01 02:25:00    153
2012-01-01 02:30:00     50
2012-01-01 02:35:00     67
2012-01-01 02:40:00    366
2012-01-01 02:45:00     17
2012-01-01 02:50:00    230
2012-01-01 02:55:00     29
2012-01-01 03:00:00     59
2012-01-01 03:05:00    437
2012-01-01 03:10:00    468
2012-01-01 03:15:00    293
2012-01-01 03:20:00    412
2012-01-01 03:25:00     48
2012-01-01 03:30:00    255
2012-01-01 03:35:00    260
2012-01-01 03:40:00     98
2012-01-01 03:45:00    132
2012-01-01 03:50:00    252
2012-01-01 03:55:00     75
2012-01-01 04:00:00    441
2012-01-01 04:05:00    379
```

I change the index to "dttm_utc"

```
df.set_index('dttm_utc', inplace=True)
```

Finally, as the last step, I would like to resample the df, **on an hourly basis** and also do a **sum** and **mean** on the data1 on an hourly basis, so I do this:

```
df.resample('H').agg([np.sum, np.mean])
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'
```

How can I overcome this problem? Please help!

Comment: you need pandas >= 0.18.0; before 0.18 .resample() will return a frame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Pandas 0.17.1.

```
>>> df.resample('H', how=['sum', 'mean'])
                    data1            
                      sum        mean
dttm_utc                             
2012-01-01 00:00:00  2566  213.833333
2012-01-01 01:00:00  2667  222.250000
2012-01-01 02:00:00  3154  262.833333
2012-01-01 03:00:00  3897  324.750000
2012-01-01 04:00:00   329  164.500000
```